# ircii - how to set default server in ircII?

Tags: irc

I somehow set Freenode as my default server in ircII, but now I can't figure out how to change it. Is there any .irciirc file or something?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out.
The enviorment variable $IRCSERVER is the default server for ircII.
Changing it solved the problem:

```
$ export IRCSERVER="example.com"
```

And adding it to the `.bashrc` or `.profile` file makes it permanent.